# Download dompdf instead of view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, dompdf

```
$this->load->view('student/zipfile',$this->data);
$html = $this->output->get_output();
$this->load->library('pdf');
$this->dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$this->dompdf->render();
$this->dompdf->stream("welcome.pdf", array("Attachment"=>0));
```

I am successfully convert html page to pdf using `DOMpdf` library. Now, Instead of view `pdf` file I only want to direct download `pdf`. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: try `array("Attachment"=>1)`

Comment: pdf take to much time when I want only 50 result @DevsiOdedra it show fatal error. `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 104857600 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 92 bytes) `

Comment: if you include css file, then put only required css only for that page, if you put extra css then it will take time.

Comment: Actually I am using internal css which is around 75 line @DevsiOdedra

Comment: @navi always tries to inline CSS and table structure for pdf.

Comment: it ok, put only required css, and dompdf having issue of taking lime, you can check in issue list.

Comment: Ok and thanks once again for the clarification @DevsiOdedra

Answer (score 1):

Use the below command.

```
$this->dompdf->download("welcome.pdf");
```

For this error Fatal error: The allowed memory size of 104857600 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 92 bytes)

Answer: You have to increase memory size